# Error when comparing two dataframes based on a key

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and I'm attempting to compare the two dataframes, so if the value of df1 is in df, drop the row. I've listed out both columns, and they're named exactly alike.

So in my code below, I rename the column in another dataframe (df3) so that I can merge them into a new dataframe (df1). I attempt to set the index to the permit values, but don't wish to drop the index (because I want to keep the permit numbers), then compare them.

```
df   Permit Number  Sub Permit   
     BLD-00045         NaN          
     ELE-2019        BLD-00045     
     PLM-2018        BLD-00045
```

```
df1  Permit Number    Sub Permit    
     BLD-00001         NaN          
     ELE-2019         BLD-00045     
     PLM-7777         BLD-00045
```

So my goal would be to keep the rows BLD-00045 and PLM-7777, but drop ELE-2019 because it's equal between the two dataframes.

```
df3.rename(columns={'permit_num': "Permit Number"}, inplace=True)
df1 = pd.merge(df, df3, on='Permit Number')
df.set_index('Permit Number', inplace=False)
df1.set_index('Permit Number', inplace=False)
df = df.loc[df['Permit Number'] != df1['Permit Number']]
print(df)
```

I keep getting ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series object.

Comment: Can you post the initial dataframes so others can replicate the issue easily? See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for a guide on asking questions

Comment: Your issue is probably that `df` and `df3` have different indexes. You can only compare series like that if they have the same indices. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.equals.html. Seperately your `set_index` lines won't actually do anything, you either need to assign this to another variable or use `in_place=True`